# Ansible error when delete the file (this module requires key=value arguments)

Tags: ansible

I get the following error when I try to delete a file:

```
TASK: [mulecore | Delete the anchor.txt file] ********************************* 
failed:  => {"failed": true}
msg: this module requires key=value arguments (['the_file.stdout', 'state-absent'])

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

This is my task:

```
- file: the_file.stdout state = absent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mark file as path parameter:

```
- file: path=the_file.stdout state=absent
```

Comment: remove the space between state and absent should be like this state=absent

Comment: Done, Thanks for your advice.